# CSS transform and max-height

Tags: jquery, css

I have an image with css max-height and max-width set

I have added a link to rotate the image.

so the jQuery code looks something like

```
rotate = rotate - 90;
$("#thumbnail1").css('transform','rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)');
```

This part works,

But when it rotates, it ignores the max-height

here is a screen shot showing what currently happens

[image]

What I want to happen, is that the image should not be outside the background border.

below is relevant code and css

```css
.thumbouter {
    width: 191px;
    height: 145px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.thumbouter .thumbnail {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.thumbnail {
    width: 191px;
    height: 146px;
    position: relative;
}
.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
}

#thumbnail1 {
    display: block;
    max-width: 182px;
    max-height: 137px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbouter pull-left"> <span class="thumbnail"> <img id="thumbnail1"   src="1467075448.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true" style="display: block;"> </span><span class="rotate-left" data="1">L</span><span class="rotate-right" data="1">R</span></div>
```

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/c88be4t0/6/)

Comment: You can try to add `overflow: hidden;` in `.thumbnail`.

Comment: charlie can put this on jsfiddle?

Comment: I have added a link to jsFiddle to the bottom of the post

Comment: The hint provided by @JimmyKo is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you rotate 90 degrees, you want to set `max-width` to fit the container's height, instead of `max-height`, because your image is now turned sideways.

Try this:

```
var maxWidth = $("#thumbnail1").css('max-width');
var maxHeight = $("#thumbnail1").css('max-height');
rotate = rotate - 90;
$("#thumbnail1").css({
    'transform':'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)',
    'max-width': maxHeight,
    'max-height': maxWidth
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to apply the css property 
`Overflow:hidden`to .thumbnail div.

Check following fiddle,

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/c88be4t0/8)

Comment: Nope. It won't keep the ratio. The image needs to fit in its container.